# Check DocumentSet exist in SharePoint 2013 Document Library using C# CSOM

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013, csom, sharepointdocumentlibrary, document-set

I've a requirement to check whether a documentset exists in Sharepoint 2013 Document Library.

I have a Document Library, it has a folder, and inside the folder there are a few DocumentSets, however I need to check whether a particular documentset exists by passing it a Title.

Url will looks like: /Library/Folder/Documentset_name

Can anybody offer a reference/solution for this?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the SharePoint Api to achieve this.

Look at [Api documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841.aspx#bk_FileCollection).

You will get all files with metadata in json format with

*http:///_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('/')/files*

After that you can check if the response contains your filename.

---

An even better solution is to use the filter function in the request.

See [this reference](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/35796.sharepoint-2013-using-rest-api-for-selecting-filtering-sorting-and-pagination-in-sharepoint-list.aspx) for more information.